# How to Secure HTML email in a web application?

Tags: security, html-email, pop3, spam-prevention, antivirus

What is the most effective way of sanitizing HTML emails displayed in a web application so that malicious code is not executable, but the html layout remains in tact?

An example of the desired functionality is the way gmail removes any script tags and delays image display.

I can use some naive regex tag stripper to try and secure the email as best I can, but what I'm looking for is a comprehensive filter that ideally sits between the client and pop server.

Does anyone have any insights into this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you read the answers to [Strict HTML Validation and Filtering in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/199017/781723), which asks the same question.  [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org) is a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you something like http://htmlpurifier.org/ or if you use php: https://phpids.org/

Don't write your own regexp rules, they will fail! :)

To make some advertisement, if you use php, you can try my PHP Intrusion Prevention System, its Alpha but I need testers :)

http://ra23.net/wop/some_phpips/

Its a little Framework around phpids.

Comment: Are you sure that phpids solves this problem?  I don't think I'd rely upon it to solve this particular problem.

Comment: afaik it implements htmlpurifier too. So it is able to check for malicious code, if he wants to do so. I see no reason, why not using it. It willt ake a little patience to get the filter working for e-mails, but I think it is possible.