# Fix Html / Xhtml Markup Errors?

Tags: html, xhtml, w3c-validation

Is  there a tool to help fix Html errors and warnings?  I just checked my code against the W3 Validator and found hundreds of errors and warnings.

Preferably something that can work with php

Comment: check out this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199017/strict-html-validation-and-filtering-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) a try. I don't know about PHP, but there seems to be an extension for HTML Tidy [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php).

However, I recommend that you try to fix the errors/warnings yourself because this way you'll learn how to write valid HTML. You'll find that fixing a single error will usually cause a chain reaction of fixes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are validating your code, you must double check what doctype you used.  If you are using strict you must know which elements will work with it.  For instance, according to strict iframes are invalid but in transitional they are accepted.  This should help you get rid of some or most of your errors.  The validator tells you what the error is and an idea of how to fix it.  I would suggest looking through it and fix your errors one by one.

I also recommend getting a program called Notepad++.  It is a free text editor that makes it easier to recognize errors by color coding your code.  There is another program called HTML validator that is a text editor / validator combined.  It also color codes your code and it has a built in validator.  You can get a free trial but the full version costs between $60 and $90.

I have not come across a validator for php, although HTML validator may also help with php as well.  Hope this was helpful.

Comment: If you think you have too many errors it may also be easier to rewrite the page.  Look around www.w3schools.com if you have any questions on doctypes and what is accepted.